# How to traverse through n elements in a doubly linked list in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, ansi-c

As the title suggests, I have to iterate through a doubly linked list.  The only problem is that I have to iterate through "n" elements.

For example, if I'm given a list of, 1 3 2 2 1 1, I have to iterate left or right depending on the value I'm on so:

1 -> 3 -> 1 -> 1.  I can move over the same value as the value in the list.  Since I start at 1, I can move left or right 1 element (can only go right).  When I land on 3 I can move left or right 3 elements etc.

```
while (temp->next != NULL) {
   //traverse n elements left or right
}
```

If I always just had to traverse 1 elements at a time it's as easy as

```
temp = temp->next;
```

If someone could explain a strategy to traversing 'n' elements depending on the value of the node, that would be much appreciated.

edit: You can only go in the direction if there are enough elements in that direction.  So in the case of 1 -> 3, you can only go 3 to the right after.

Comment: just traverse again in another while loop..

Comment: Just a detail: in the case of `1 -> 3 -> ...` as you show, you can go right one to `3`. Now you can go left or right. But if you go left, do you go at all, or do you stop at `1`? Also, for a doubly linked list, you need two pointers in each node: a `next` and `previous`. Just use a loop to iterate going through successive `next` or `previous` pointers based upon the value of the current node.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, you can only go in the direction if theres enough elements in that direction.  So you can't go 3 left at all because there isn't enough elements.

Comment: What you are trying to get as a output.Say for your own example what you want as output?

Comment: Well overall I'm just trying to produce a true/false.  The output is true if a path can be established from the first element to the last and the output is false if a path cannot be established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is to traverse through **n** elements, where **n** is the value of the current node.
The code would be like ~

```
int tr;
while (temp->next != NULL)
{
     tr=temp->data; // temp->data holds the value of the current node.
     Node *leftptr = temp, *rightptr = temp;
     while(tr!=0 && rightptr!=NULL) //moves right side
     {
          rightptr = rightptr->next;
          tr--;
     }
     tr=temp->data;
     while(tr!=0 && leftptr!=NULL) //moves left side
     {
          leftptr = leftptr->prev;
          tr--;
     }
}
```

You can implement your algorithm and choose how to traverse, given both the traversal rules.

Comment: `tr` will be uninitialized if `temp` is the only node.

Comment: As i said earlier, it depends on the algorithm and how is it going to be implemented. For your question, we can use conditional constructs to do that.